# I am working with react native i want to remove the event listener inside the useEffect return statement but removeEventListener is depracted

Tags: react-native, return, use-effect, event-listener, removeeventlistener

[image: how to use remove function in reactnative]

I want to remove eventlistener in react native but removeEventListener is deprecated in react native

Answer (score 10):

in the latest react native versions you can do this instead

```js
const btnWidthHandler = () => {
    setbtnwidth(Dimensions.get("window").width / 4)
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dimensionsHandler = Dimensions.addEventListener('change',btnWidthHandler)
  return () => dimensionsHandler.remove()
}, [])
```